# box2d check if a point is in a fixture

Tags: box2d

Does box2d expose some computational geometry functions like checking whether a point is inside a fixture?

I'd like to sample a random point uniformly over the intersection of two fixtures. Since I do not need to generate an explicit representation of the intersection of the two shapes, I'm going to generate the random point uniformly over the intersection of the axis-aligned bounding boxes, and then reject samples that aren't within both fixtures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. b2Fixture has a TestPoint(b2Vec2) function.
Take a look at the header file for b2Fixture here:
http://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Fixture.h#154